# Como fazer um delete com Angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Criei uma classe para fazer um delete de dados de um banco mas não sei como chamo a mesma classe pelo Angular 4 no codigo html.

```
//Classe Delete
deleteClient(client): void {
    if(this.client.id){
        this.clientService.deleteClient(client).then(msg => this.returnMsg = msg);
    }else{

    }
}
```

**html**

```
<td>
   <button (click)='deleteClient()'>Delete</button>
   <button>
      <a [routerLink]="['/detail', client.id]">
        Details
      </a> 
   </button>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você poderia declarar uma variável

```
http:Http
```

E depois utilizar um post ou http

```
 deleteClient(idcliente){
   this.http.get("url:porta&idcliente="idcliente)
    .subscribe(result => {
       console.log(result.json())
    });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você não chama ela no HTML. você precisa atribuir uma função no (click) do seu botão,o que você ja fez.

E aí no .js do seu componente, você precisa importar essa sua classe de delete, criar uma função dentro do seu componente (a mesma que você atribuiu no seu HTML), e dentro dessa função chamar o método de sua classe.

Comment: Fiz tudo o que vc falou, importei a classe e criei uma função dentro do componente. Estou com dificuldade em relação a sintaxe pra chamar a mesma. Vou colocar o codigo todo abaixo.

Answer (score 0):

Coloquei o código do component que criei e da view pra ficar mais fácil a compreensão. No caso da view em html eu criei uma tabela com os dados de cadastro dos clientes e um botão para deletar os mesmos, onde o botão deletaria de acordo com o id do client. A minha duvida é com relação a sintaxe, ja procurei em varias documentações e não consegui a resposta.

```
//Codigo do componte.ts que esta sendo usado
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {ClientService} from '../services/client.service';
import { Client } from '../client-register/client';
import { Message } from '../client-register/message';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-client-list',
  templateUrl: './client-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./client-list.component.css']
})

export class ClientListComponent implements OnInit {

  clients: Client[] = [];
  @Input() client: Client = new Client();
  returnMsg: Message;



  constructor(
    private clientService: ClientService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.clientService.getClients().then(clients => this.clients = clients);
  }

  deleteClient(client): void {
    if(this.client.id){
        this.clientService.deleteClient(client)
        .then(msg => this.returnMsg = msg);
    }else{

    }
 }

}

//Codigo Html da pagina
<h2>ACME - CLIENTS LIST</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>User Name</th>
          <th>Birth Date</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody *ngFor="let client of clients">
        <tr>
          <td>
            {{client.name}}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{client.userName}}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{client.birthDate}}
          </td>
          <td>

          </td>
          <td>

            <button>
              <button (click)='deleteClient(client)'>Delete</button>
              <a [routerLink]="['/detail', client.id]">
                Details
              </a> 
            </button>

          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>


  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Edite a pergunta com o seu código. Não poste ele como uma resposta.